# boto3 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

I'm trying to use boto3 to print the values of an EC2 tag I have called 'Function' but receive a `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` error in line 7 after the code runs through about 20 objects.  I've tried to catch this by checking if that value is `None` but still receive this error.

```
import boto3
s = boto3.Session(profile_name='default')
ec2 = s.resource('ec2')

for i in ec2.instances.all():
  for tag in i.tags:
    if tag['Value'] is None:
      print("No Value")
    else:
      if tag['Key'] == 'Function':
        print(tag['Value'])
```

Comment: Which line causes the exception? Could it be that i.tags is None?

Comment: It's line7 so that would make sense.  If I add a `if i.tags is None: print("No Value")` I receive the same issue also in line 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try doing this and check:

```
def tag_to_dict(ec2):
    tag_dict = {}
    if ec2.tags is None: 
        return "No Value"    ## Replace "No Value" with tag_dict to get an empty dict
    for tag in ec2.tags:
        tag_dict[tag['Key']] = tag['Value']  
    return tag_dict
```

You end up getting a dictionary with keys as keys and tag values as values.

---

**Edit:**

Try and see if you can get anything here:

```
for i in ec2.instances.all():
    if i.tags is None:
        continue
    for tag in i.tags:
        if tag['Key'] == 'Function':
            print(tag['Value'])
```

It continues with the next iteration of the loop and ignores `NoneType` values.

Comment: Sorry not following this but maybe I need to just go learn more about dictionaries.  It runs fine but displays not data.  I've tried adding a print statement but still returns nothing.

Comment: @tweeks200- Please try the edited answer and see if it prints any data.

Comment: tried that and receive the same NoneType error as before.  I also tried combining with my original but no luck there.  It does print about 20 correct values before throwing the error.

Comment: @tweeks200- Some changes have been made to my answer. If you are still not getting any data after 20 values, it means that there are no more data available.

Comment: thanks that handles the situation correctly.  I think what was happening is that some of my instances are not tagged, or tagged incorrectly and it was failing when getting to one of them.  Thanks again!